# WPF Array of UserControls

Tags: wpf, vb.net, arrays, wpf-controls

I am working on a project and there are about 30 controls that I need to call and update at runtime.  I have named the controls day0 - day35 (it is a calendar).  Basically, at runtime, I need to call each control's setDate function to display the day number.  When I run it, the array just has null/empty.

This is the array I am trying to use in the code behind.  The controls are names day0-day35.

```
Private dateArr() As ucMonthDay = {day0, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, _
                          day6, day7, day8, day9, _
                          day10, day11, day12, day13, day14, day15, day16, day17, day18, day19, _
                          day20, day21, day22, day23, day24, day25, day26, day27, day28, day29, _
                                  day30, day31, day32, day33, day34}
```

Then I want to be able to loop through this array and set the date on each of the controls:

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    While (counter < 35)
        dateArr(counter).setDate(firstDay)
        firstDay.AddDays(1)
        counter += 1
    End While
```

When this gets called, I get a null pointer exception.  I do not understand why the controls are not in the array?

Thanks for your help.

Kevin

Comment: after looking at it for a while, it works if I set dateArr in the userControl loaded event.  I am still not sure why I cannot set the value in the declaration, but this will work.  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Where are the controls initialized?  Is day0 an x:Name in Xaml, or is it explicitly declared and initialized with "new" somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is an x:Name.  It is created within XAML code.  The initialization is done by WPF (it does not have any custom initialization).

Comment: OK.  Then you just need to make sure that InitializeComponent() is called before anything is done with ucMonthDay, as all of the objects in it get initialized during InitializeComponent().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create your objects